# Where does the "rectified" in ReLU come from?

Tags: deep-learning, terminology, activation-functions, relu

ReLU stands for Rectified Linear Unit. Linear Unit, I understand, since the function is piecewise linear. But what does rectified mean?

I looked up the definition and it said:

> denoting an electric current that has been converted from alternating current to direct current

But I don't quite see how this can connect to ReLU function. While it does have a bend at $x = 0$ indicating a change in direction, not sure how I can work this into the idea of current directions.

Comment: I always linked it to engineering, a rectifier converts alternating current into direct current. As ReLU gets rid of the negative side of the linear function I think its fitting. Not sure though if thats also what the authors had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is by analogy with an electrical rectifier. A rectifier allows current to flow in one direction but blocks current in the other direction. Or if you prefer it allows voltage in one polarity but won't allow a voltage in the opposite polarity. Which is also what a ReLU does.